# AnimatedGifEncoder android issue

Tags: android, gif

That's what I get when I try to addFrame(). Have anyone faced with that?

```
08-28 18:04:37.371 511-1685/? E/audio_hw_utils: 

audio_extn_utils_send_app_type_cfg: Could not get ctl for mixer cmd - Audio Stream 43 App Type Cfg
08-28 18:04:37.371 511-1685/? E/voice: voice_is_in_call_rec_stream: input stream is NULL
08-28 18:04:37.371 511-1685/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
08-28 18:04:37.393 511-1685/? E/voice: voice_is_in_call_rec_stream: input stream is NULL
08-28 18:04:37.394 511-1685/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB_CMD_GET_AUDPROC_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE Returned = -19
08-28 18:04:37.394 511-1685/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB audproc returned = -19
08-28 18:04:37.394 511-1685/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
08-28 18:04:37.394 511-1685/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AFE returned = -19
08-28 18:04:37.395 511-1685/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there wasn't a problem. It was ok to just ignore that. The problem was a high resolution of images. Encoder just needs a huge amount of time to process all of them. To solve that I just decreased the resolution of images. I hope that will help somebody.